# Duration (remaining) for Living World content

Tags: guild-wars-2

Every few weeks, new [Living World](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Living_Story) content is released. And with that, every few weeks the old Living World content stops and goes 'away'. Currently, Blood and Madness is running at the same time as Tower of Nightmares. Normally, the old one (BaM) would make way for the new one (ToN).

Is there any place or any way to view how long Living World content will stay? GuildwarsWiki only shows when it started.

Comment: I'd be shocked if it only ran for two weeks from Oct 28th.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is very suitable for the site. The answer ends up varying for many of the Living World events, as some end up staying around 2 weeks, but others stay for 4, like this one. LW events during the summer also varied this way as well.

Comment: I was hoping to find a set rotation/duration/statement from ArenaNet to figure this out, rather then guessing by the contents of the content.

Comment: As much as I'd like to know the "official" schedule myself, I don't think there is an answer other than "whatever ArenaNet thinks will work best". It used to be a monthly cycle, but has been switched to a fortnightly cycle (every other Tuesday), with some content staying for more than one cycle and some even becoming (semi-)permanent (e.g. Scarlet attacks still seem to be happening). That doesn't make this an unsuitable question imho, it just makes it one with no easy correct answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually no explicit indication when exactly a Living World "episode" ends, but there is a fairly obvious pattern:

- A major Living World episode will begin early (first week) in the month, and
  last until the next major episode starts, a month later. This will
  be some new event in Tyria.
- Then a minor episode will begin around the middle (14th-18th or so) of
  the month. It will be related to the current major episode, usually furthering its story. The two will both be available (possibly with some details shuffled off) for the next two weeks.
- Holiday events don't have an established pattern yet, but judging by Blood and Madness, they will run entirely in parallel to story episodes. Duration may vary.

Of course, those are just guidelines that ArenaNet may or may not follow. Watch for their updates and announcements. They probably won't retire their current episode until a new one starts, and if the announcement seems to be related to the current episode, it will probably be a minor one.

Or maybe it's just a 4-week cycle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the next release is inside the tower and is launching on November 12th 2013. If this is the case and you assume a 2 week schedule of play for it that would mean it ended on November 26th 2013. The Nightmares Within release states that Kessex Hills will remain 'polluted' whilst the Tower is breached, so it stands that the Tower of Nightmares release will remain active.

Presumably, vanquishing the denizens of the tower will lead to it's demise at this time. So it would be safe to assume that it would be removed from the game at this point. However it's an educated guess, so could be subject to change as more data is revealed.

This would be backed up by the onset of the holiday season in early December meaning that the release following Nightmares Within may well be the Wintersday 2013 release. So I would assume that Blood and Madness must end before the Wintersday content can be put into the game. So it could be that Blood and Madness will end on November 12th, as this would preserve the current two release overlap.

Reference: https://www.guildwars2.com/en/the-game/releases/november-12-2013/